# Adding SOCKS Proxy support in CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: objective-c, proxy, cocoaasyncsocket

I added SOCKS ability to CocoaAsyncSocket. I first tried to do this on GCDAsyncSocket, but failed.

For CocoaAsyncSocket, I simply set SOCKS properties on the read/write stream in this method (In GCDAsyncSocket, only iOS used read/write sockets using CFSocket)
This was pasted in the method
- (BOOL)createStreamsToHost:(NSString *)hostname onPort:(UInt16)port error:(NSError **)errPtr

```
    NSLog(@"Setting SOCKS proxy: %@:%d", theProxyHost, theProxyPort);

    CFDictionaryRef proxyDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
    CFMutableDictionaryRef socksConfig = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, proxyDict);
    CFDictionarySetValue(socksConfig, kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxyHost, (CFStringRef)theProxyHost);
    CFDictionarySetValue(socksConfig, kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxyPort, (__bridge CFNumberRef)[NSNumber numberWithInteger:theProxyPort]);
    CFDictionarySetValue(socksConfig, kCFStreamPropertySOCKSVersion, kCFStreamSocketSOCKSVersion4);

    CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)theReadStream, kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy, socksConfig);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)theWriteStream, kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy, socksConfig);
    CFRelease(proxyDict);
```

It works well, as it routes all traffic through the Proxy.
But either I don't understand how proxies work, or I did something wrong, because:

```
if(![socket connectToHost:@"somedomain.com" onPort:9567 error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not connect: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

This always returns true, regardless if the server responds. Because the Proxy responds. CocoaAsyncSocket's delegate method

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
```

is called with host and port of the proxy server, not the server that I called connectToHost:onPort:error on.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?